# Does the AddressEntry object have a property like Index Number to find persons with the same name?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am reading data from my global Exchange Address Book.

This works for names that do not have duplicates.

When I find a name that is there many times, I need to loop through the whole address book.

I would rather try to get the first index of the name I am looking for.
For example "Peter Name" from the AddressEntry-Object and use this index to loop through the next AddressEntries.
If "Peter Name"'s index would be "1", I could then loop through for example from entry 2 to entry 10.

Is there an index to the AddressEntry object or do I need to rethink finding persons with the same name?

Comment: Please show us your code - it will get far easier to give you some help if there is something to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no intrinsic index property since there is no intrinsic sort order. There is the  `EntryID` property, but it is not an index, but a unique id.

If you want to process all duplicate names, looping through all entries is a bad idea - some GALs contain tens of thousands of entries and might not even let you loop through them at all.

In Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), you can use a `PR_ANR` restriction to get a list of duplicates similar to what Outlook displays when you resolve a duplicate name in Outlook. That functionality is not however exposed in the Outlook Object Model. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use [RDOAddressList](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressList.htm).`ResolveNameEx` method:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set AdrrEntries = Session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx("Peter Name")
for each AE in AdrrEntries
    MsgBox AE.Name
next
```